# unable to create jar file in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, jar, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to create a jar file with command
`jar cfm ProductSalePerCountry.jar Manifest.txt SalesCountry/*.class` and i got

```
The program 'jar' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * fastjar
 * gcj-5-jdk
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * gcj-4.9-jdk
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless
```

also I am unable to use `nps` command. Currently I have jdk1.8.0_131 installed in my ubuntu 16.04. Please suggest  to resolve the issue.

Comment: How did you get Java installed in the first place?

Comment: I followed [link](http://www.guru99.com/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu.html) to install java.

Comment: What is the output from `type java`?

Comment: output is `hduser_@tanuj-VPCEH38FN:/home/tanuj/MapReduceTutorial$ type java
java is /usr/bin/java` @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen

Comment: Ok. Even though you have installed Java manually you are using the one that came with ubuntu. Run `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: Thanks it is working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though you followed instructions on how to install Oracle Java, you are using one provided by Ubuntu.  The default here is just to install `java` and not any of the tools (like jar or javac) present in the Java Development Kit.  The simplest solution is just to install one in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

This will install the OpenJDK flavor of Java which is slightly different from Oracle Java, but not in ways that matter at your current level.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with Oracle Java, then you can follow http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/ for easy install. This will set all paths and functionality to use.